# Can I validate a password before encryption in Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, validation, encryption, passwords

I made a SpringBoot application and now I'm at the login part.
I've made some custom restrictions with a custom annotation.
The problem is that this custom annotation is applied to the user after the password has been ecncripted.

This is the PasswordConstraint

```
public class PasswordConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassword, User>{

@Override
public void initialize(final ValidPassword arg0){}

@SneakyThrows
@Override
public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    Properties props         = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("passay.properties");
    props.load(inputStream);
    MessageResolver resolver = new PropertiesMessageResolver(props);


    PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator(resolver, Arrays.asList(
            new LengthRule(8, 16),
            new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.UpperCase, 1),
            new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.LowerCase, 1),
            new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Digit, 1),
            new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Special, 1),
            new WhitespaceRule(),
            new IllegalSequenceRule(EnglishSequenceData.Alphabetical, 5, false),
            new IllegalSequenceRule(EnglishSequenceData.Numerical, 5, false)
    ));

    RuleResult result = validator.validate(new PasswordData(user.getPasswordHash()));
    if (result.isValid()) {
        return true;
    }

    List<String> messages  = validator.getMessages(result);
    String messageTemplate = String.join(",", messages);

    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(messageTemplate)
            .addConstraintViolation()
            .disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

    return false;

}
```

}

This is where I encrypt the password

```
 @Qualifier("getPasswordEncoder")
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public void registerNewUserAccount(User user){
    Optional<User> userOptional= userRepository.findUserByEmailAddress(user.getEmailAddress());
    if(userOptional.isPresent()){
        throw new IllegalStateException("email taken!");
    }

    // Se comenteaza pentru ca: Validarea parolei se face pe hashPassword
    //Dupa rezolvarea problemei, se decomenteaza
    user.setPasswordHash(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordHash()));

    user.setEnabled(false);

    Optional<User> saved = Optional.of(user);
    saved.ifPresent(u -> {
        try {
            String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            verificationTokenService.save(user, token);

            try {
                emailService.sendHtmlMail(u);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


    userRepository.save(user);
    System.out.println(user);

    saved.get();

}
```

Here is the user:

```
@Entity
@Table
@ValidPassword
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( //se auto-incrementeaza pkul ?
            name = "user_sequence",
            sequenceName = "user_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue( ///??????????
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,//maybe auto if not working
            generator = "user_sequence"
    )
    //TODO Change camelCase to python_format
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    @NonNull
    @NotBlank(message = "New password is mandatory")
    private String passwordHash;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Email
    private String emailAddress;
    public String address1;
    public String address2;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String zipcode;
    private boolean enabled;
```

Comment: 1. Get the raw password from the user. 2. Validate the raw password. 3a. If the raw password is invalid reject it and ask the user for a valid password. 3b. If the password is valid proceed with the encryption.  What step do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when you save an entity to the database, the validation annotations are also checked, which will then trigger the `ConstraintViolationException`.

So the best approach is to follow the [Data Transfer Object](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern) pattern. I suggest you create a new class say `UserDto` which will be similar or even a replica of your `User` entity, ideally your `UserDto` class should only contain the field that the controller needs inclusive of all the necessary validation annotations.

In the `service` class where you encrypted your password, before saving the user, convert the `UserDto` instance to a `User` entity but remember to remove the `@ValidPassword` annotation from the User entity since you don't want to validate the encrypted password and you've already checked for the validations from your UserDto class

***Remember**: `UserDto` should not be an entity class since we don't want it in our database, we only need it for validation purpose.*